# dropdown menu looks weird in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a dropdown menu that isnt working in ie7 but works in other browsers

http://redlineautoleasing.com/beta/

its using jquery but i cant figure out how to fix it , any clues?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a width to the submenu UL, currently IE8 (sorry no IE7) displays each item horizontally.

Setting a `width`, as well as perhaps `overflow:hidden;` may help.

(totally untested)